# Proving an Invariance Property of Chordal Loewner Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Given that $g_t(z)$ is the solution for $\partial_tg_t(z) = \dfrac{2}{g_t(z) - \lambda(t)}$ with the initial value $g_o(z) = z$. How do I prove that, for fixed $t_0$, the function $h_{t,t_0}(z) = g_{t+t_0} \circ g_{t_0}^{-1}(z)$, satisfies $\partial _th_t(z) = \dfrac{2}{h_t(z) - \lambda(t_0 +t)}$

In better words, how would I prove that if $g_t(z)$ is the chordal Loewner map driven by $\lambda(t)$ then  $h_{t,t_0}(z) = g_{t+t_0} \circ g_{t_0}^{-1}(z)$ is the chordal loewner map driven by $\lambda(t_0 +t)$

This is a specific part from a more general statement about chordal Loewner Equations in [Basic properties of SLE](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0106036.pdf) (porposition 2.1). My main problem is how to differentiate the given composition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's decompose the problem:
$$
y=g_{t_0}^{-1}(z)~~\text{ solves }~~ z=g_{t_0}(y)
$$
Then 
$$
h_{s,t_0}(z)=g_{t_0+s}(y).
$$
So you identify solutions of the original problem by their (unique) value at time $t_0$ and then advance that solution to time $t_0+t$. The differential equation at time $t_0+t$ reads as
$$
∂_tg_{t_0+t}(y)=\frac{2}{g_{t_0+t}(y)+λ(t_0+t)}
$$
Now replace back $h(z)$ for $g(y)$ to get
$$
∂_th_{t,t_0}(z)=\frac{2}{h_{t,t_0}(z)+λ(t_0+t)}.
$$
So your transformation is just a re-parametrization of the original equation.